# How to Create ODBC on MAC

Tags: macos, odbc

I wanted to create and use ODBC in my Mac (Big Sur OS) in order to extract data to my excel worksheet direct from SQL Server.

First time i'm using MAC as my boss required me to change from PC to Mac.

Thank you.

Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

MySQL site has a page regarding ODBC connection - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-macos.html

I also like to use DBeaver when working with databases on MacOS.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Z, i've been through the process stated in the MySQL page.  Something went bonkers so still trying to make everything work.